# Composing Scalaz 7 Validations

Tags: scala, scalaz

I would like to compose checks that return Scalaz 7 `Validation`s. I made a simple example of parsing a sequence of words and constructing a Person object from them. Parsing can fail at many steps and we fail-fast in that case, with the error message of what was the failure. The example below is totally made up and stupid as is, but is as close to what I want to achieve as I could provide.

Looking at my for comprehension below, it seems there must be a better way to compose validations than that.

1. Initial sequence is changed a few times, from `seq` to `seq2` to `seq3`. When calling for example `lastNameValidation`, it needs to explicitly be called with `seq2`, even though it is called right after `seq2 = onlyShort(seq)`.
2. I read about Kleisli arrow composition, when one can compose `A => M[B]` and `B => M[C]` to get an arrow `A => M[C]` (where `M` is a monad). However, I here don't always compose things in such a way that the next step would reuse computation from the previous one. That, and I couldn't get Kleisli arrow composition work with Scalaz 7.

Code:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

case class Address(streetName: String, streetNumber: Int)
case class Person(name: String, lastName: String, age: Int, address: Address)

def nameValidation(seq: List[String]) = seq.find(Set("John", "Carol", "Susan").contains(_)).toSuccess("Name not found")
def lastNameValidation(seq: List[String]) = seq.find(Set("Kennedy", "Hardy", "Taplin").contains(_)).toSuccess("Last name not found")
def lengthValidation(lastName: String) = lastName.size.success[String]
def dyValidation(lastName: String) = if (!lastName.contains("dy")) Failure("Not the person") else Success(123)
def streetNumberValidation(seq: List[String]) = seq.find(_.forall(_.isDigit)).map(_.toInt).toSuccess("Could not extract street number")
def streetValidation(seq: List[String]) = seq.find(Set("Bush Street", "Pine Street", "Market Street").contains(_)).toSuccess("Street not found")

def onlyShort(seq: List[String]) = seq.filter(_.size < 15)
def omitGarbage(seq: List[String]) = seq.filter(_ != "garbage")

def createPerson(seq: List[String]) = for {
  name <- nameValidation(seq)
  seq2 = onlyShort(seq)
  lastName <- lastNameValidation(seq2)
  length <- lengthValidation(lastName)
  dy <- dyValidation(lastName)
  seq3 = omitGarbage(seq2)
  streetNumber <- streetNumberValidation(seq3)
  street <- streetValidation(seq3)
} yield Person(name, lastName, 80, Address(street, streetNumber))

createPerson(List("255", "a very long string", "Bush Street", "Hardy", "San Francisco", "John", "garbage"))

createPerson(List("a very long string", "Bush Street", "Hardy", "San Francisco", "John", "garbage"))
```

Any scalaz/functional guru's advice is very welcome!

REPL:

```
scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> case class Address(streetName: String, streetNumber: Int)
defined class Address

scala> case class Person(name: String, lastName: String, age: Int, address: Address)
defined class Person

scala> def nameValidation(seq: List[String]) = seq.find(Set("John", "Carol", "Susan").contains(_)).toSuccess("Name not found")
nameValidation: (seq: List[String])scalaz.Validation[java.lang.String,String]

scala> def lastNameValidation(seq: List[String]) = seq.find(Set("Kennedy", "Hardy", "Taplin").contains(_)).toSuccess("Last name not found")
lastNameValidation: (seq: List[String])scalaz.Validation[java.lang.String,String]

scala> def lengthValidation(lastName: String) = lastName.size.success[String]
lengthValidation: (lastName: String)scalaz.Validation[String,Int]

scala> def dyValidation(lastName: String) = if (!lastName.contains("dy")) Failure("Not the person") else Success(123)
dyValidation: (lastName: String)Product with Serializable with scalaz.Validation[java.lang.String,Int]

scala> def streetNumberValidation(seq: List[String]) = seq.find(_.forall(_.isDigit)).map(_.toInt).toSuccess("Could not extract street number")
streetNumberValidation: (seq: List[String])scalaz.Validation[java.lang.String,Int]

scala> def streetValidation(seq: List[String]) = seq.find(Set("Bush Street", "Pine Street", "Market Street").contains(_)).toSuccess("Street not found")
streetValidation: (seq: List[String])scalaz.Validation[java.lang.String,String]

scala> def onlyShort(seq: List[String]) = seq.filter(_.size < 15)
onlyShort: (seq: List[String])List[String]

scala> def omitGarbage(seq: List[String]) = seq.filter(_ != "garbage")
omitGarbage: (seq: List[String])List[String]

scala> def createPerson(seq: List[String]) = for {
     |   name <- nameValidation(seq)
     |   seq2 = onlyShort(seq)
     |   lastName <- lastNameValidation(seq2)
     |   length <- lengthValidation(lastName)
     |   dy <- dyValidation(lastName)
     |   seq3 = omitGarbage(seq2)
     |   streetNumber <- streetNumberValidation(seq3)
     |   street <- streetValidation(seq3)
     | } yield Person(name, lastName, 80, Address(street, streetNumber))
createPerson: (seq: List[String])scalaz.Validation[java.lang.String,Person]

scala> createPerson(List("255", "a very long string", "Bush Street", "Hardy", "San Francisco", "John", "garbage"))
res19: scalaz.Validation[java.lang.String,Person] = Success(Person(John,Hardy,80,Address(Bush Street,255)))

scala> createPerson(List("a very long string", "Bush Street", "Hardy", "San Francisco", "John", "garbage"))
res20: scalaz.Validation[java.lang.String,Person] = Failure(Could not extract street number)
```

Comment: Two quick comments. First, if you don't want to accumulate failures, use `\/` (or plain old `Either`), not `Validation`. Second, digging values out of a big list of strings is inherently messy, and if you can't break the problem down into smaller stages I think this is about as clean as you're going to get.

Comment: `Either` is not a Monad, so I could not compose it nicely with for-comprehension (I needed to call `.right` to get right projection). `Validation` is right-leaning by default, so it's possible to compose it nicely with for comprehensions. Another thing was that interleaving `<-` and `=` with Either just did not work. Haven't tried `\/` though.

Comment: `Validation` isn't a monad, either, and there's some debate about whether it should even have the `flatMap` method that makes the `for`-comprehension syntax possible. `\/` is a monad, and is essentially just a right-biased `Either` with some convenient additional operations.